# Why does it say: Unexpected child "flutter" found under "flutter". when I followed the instructions on the developer website?

Tags: flutter, dart

It says: "Unexpected child "flutter" found under "flutter". for my pubspec.yaml file" twice when I followed the instructions that the developer website had. I am trying to add extra fonts to my flutter project.

I have tried taking out the "flutter:" code but then it just shows another error: 
Error on line 60, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.

Also, I checked and the font files that I specified in the pubspec.yaml file were correct.

website link: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Thank you in advance!

```
name: greatapp
description: A new Flutter application.
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  flutter:
    fonts:
      - family: Futura
        fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Futura-Medium-01.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Futura-MediumItalic-02.ttf
          style: italic
```

I thought that it would just integrate the fonts but it didn't and yielded the errors that I described above.

Comment: Please link the developer website quote you are refering to

Comment: Hello! I have just added it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **spacing** in this file is **should be 2 units** for each block.

```dart
fonts:
- family: Futura
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Futura-Medium-01.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Futura-MediumItalic-02.ttf
      style: italic
```

EDIT:

```
name: greatapp
description: A new Flutter application.
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Futura
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Futura-Medium-01.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Futura-MediumItalic-02.ttf
          style: italic
```

UPDATE:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello! I just tried this and it came back with the same error.

Comment: could you post the complete pubspec file?

Comment: Hello! I have just posted it!

Comment: check now! since i have flutter 1.7 so sdk version is updated,change if needed to `sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"`

Comment: a couple of extra spaces before flutter fonts at the end was causing it

Comment: Hello! I updated flutter and tried putting this code in, but it still did not work.

Comment: works fine here. what is the error now? fixing the space fixes the error mentioned in the post.

Comment: Hello! I am so sorry. I forgot to add these pieces of code that were already in the file, I'm really sorry for that mistake on my part. The error that it is showing me now when I tried the code is:

Comment: Error on line 41, column 25 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency specification must be a string or a mapping.

   ╷


41 │   uses-material-design: true
   │                         ^^^^

   ╵
pub get failed (65)

Comment: posted my result.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help! Through your screenshot, I found that I had an extra line that said "flutter:" in my code. Thank you so much for helping me through this issue!

Comment: Ok I just did! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
assets:
    - asset/images/
    - asset/icons/

background: Image.asset(
                "asset/images/brownie.jpg"
              ),
```